# Socket connect to a ports bound to IP vs localhost

Tags: socket, bind

It is my understanding that sockets bound to ports using localhost will not be visible to the subnet because the binding is not with the nic IP address. Local processes connecting to such port will create a unix pipe instead of an IP socket. However if bound to the nic IP address the port is visible to the subnet. I want to learn the types of connections made when connecting to ports bound to localhost and the nic IP.

** Port bound to localhost **

- local process connect using localhost creates a unix pipe
- local process connect using nic IP creates a unix pipe
- foreign process connect using nic IP cannot connect

** Port bound to nic IP **

- local process connect using localhost creates a unix pipe
- local process connect using nic IP creates an IP socket
- foreign process connect using nic IP connects and creates an IP socket

Are the above statements correct? I am reviewing network programming from this site:

http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html

in hopes of more insight.

Answer (score 3):

> Local processes connecting to such port will create a unix pipe instead of an IP socket.

Whether a process uses a pipe or a socket does not depend on the interface *per se*.  It depends on which system services it calls.

To create a named pipe, the program calls **mkfifo**(2).  To get a descriptor on that file, it calls **open**(2).  **ls -l** shows a "p" in the status bits of a fifo.  Anonymous pipes, created with **pipe**(2), have no name and are invisible to processes without a common ancestor.

To create a TCP socket, it calls **socket**(2) and then **bind**(2) to assign it a name for other processes to connect to.  If the argument to **bind** is an external address, it will be visible to the network, else not.

You may be thinking of the loopback address 127.0.0.1.  If the program binds to that, it won't be visible or accessible from the network.  Only processes running on the host machine can bind or connect to the loopback address.

It is also possible to create a TCP connection over something that looks a bit like a file, known as a UNIX-domain socket.  In that case the argument to **bind** (and **connect**) has a filename.  Because the name appears in the filesystem, it *looks* a little like a pipe, but **ls -l** shows an "s" among the status bits.

If you're interested in how all these strange distinctions came to be, NetBSD distributes two papers that date from their invention and are still relevant today.  Look for *An Advanced 4.4BSD Interprocess Communication Tutorial* and *An Introductory 4.4BSD Interprocess Communication Tutorial* on the web.

Comment: I reviewed my 4.3BSD Unix OS "Imp Book" (1989). Binding on the loopback will keep traffic off the interface layer and allow local app socket connections. However binding on the machine IP allows subnet connections which (of course) pass through the interface layer/network layer/socket layer. I want to be  confident that a local app connecting with a socket to another local app bound on the machine IP will deliver traffic as if bound on the loopback. The goal is to keep traffic off the interface layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think those statements are correct. In fact, you could confirm it with a sniffer like tcpdump. If you could see traffic on "lo" interface, that means that the connection is using a unix pipe. On the other hand, if traffic is caught on "ethX", that means is using a network conection.